# Importar módulo de outra pasta

Tags: python-3.x, importação

Quero importar um modulo que se encontra em uma pasta que é irmã da pasta onde eu tenho o script, dentro do qual quero importar o outro script, ou seja:

```
logic\ 
    board.py`
    mlogic.py
    player.py
gui\
    mgui.py
```

`logic` e `gui` são as pastas irmãs, e eu estou dentro atualmente de `mgui.py` e gostaria de importar a class `Board` do script `board.py`. Com o `PyCharm`, eu faço este import `from logic.board import Board`, e funciona, mas não com o `IDLE`, porquê? Como posso resolver isto? Parece estranho que num funciona e no outro não...

Answer (score 1):

vc pode criar um "**init**.py" importanto tudo dentro da pasta, mas você tbm pode fazer from "pasta" import "nome do arquivo":
[image: importando arquivo na pasta]
na questao do init o uso e assim:
[image: usando init]

Comment: Remova as imagens e poste o código usado. Depois que digitar selecione o código e aperte Ctrl + K para que fique com aparência correta, identado, etc.

Comment: no ctrl +k n mostra o arquivo criado dentro da pasta a print e pra mostrar isso

Answer (score 0):

Primeiramente, em ambas as pastas você deve ter um arquivo `__init__.py`, após isto, algum módulo deve estar em um diretório anterior ao outro, ou você importa os dois em um python no diretório raiz de ambos!